# Can't call function of SO file from an SO file - C++ makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

My project directory is look like this:

- libs
- bins
- FooProj

  - makefile
  - foo.h
  - foo.cpp
- BarProj

  - makefile
  - bar.h
  - bar.cpp
- MainProj

  - makefile
  - main.cpp
- makefile

FooProj and BarProj are **shared-libraries** projects (compiled to so files).

The problem is when bar.cpp call to a function from foo.h (which is in a different shared-library) I got compilation error on main.cpp that says undefined reference to foo().

```
g++ -std=c++14 -rdynamic -g -I../FooProj/ -I../BarProj/ -L../libs/ main.cpp -o ../bins/run -lFooProj -lBarProj
../libs//libBarProj.so: undefined reference to `foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/builds/test/MainProj'
makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are my coded files:

```
//foo.h
#ifndef _FOO_
#define _FOO_
void foo();
#endif

//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
```

makefile of FooProj

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -rdynamic -fPIC -g
LDFLAGS = -shared

TARGET  = ../libs/libFooProj.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
```

.

```
//bar.h
#ifndef _BAR_
#define _BAR_
void bar();
#endif

//bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
void bar()
{
    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "call foo function:" << std::endl;
    foo();
}
```

makefile of BarProj

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -rdynamic -pthread -fPIC -g -L../libs/ -lFooProj -I../FooProj/
LDFLAGS = -shared

TARGET  = ../libs/libBarProj.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bar.h"
int main()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

makefile of MainProj:

```
#include "bar.h"
int main()
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

makefile of the entire project:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) all -C FooProj/
    $(MAKE) all -C BarProj/
    $(MAKE) all -C MainProj/
```

What should I do to fix this problem? I don't understand why my BarProj shared-lib can't call to a function from FooProj.

Comment: Actually, it works for me. You missed Makefile for MainProj in description, but anyway command from log do its job. Probably, your previous builds failed? Try to make a clean in project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the BarProj's makefile.
I removed -lFooProj from CXXFLAGS and put it here in the end of the line:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
```

That fixed the problem.

The full BarProj's makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -rdynamic -pthread -fPIC -g -L../libs/ -I../FooProj/
LDFLAGS = -shared

TARGET  = ../libs/libBarProj.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS) -lFooProj
```